# How can I collect several items for every iteration of a recursive function

Tags: recursion, clojure, lisp

I want to create several items for each call to a recursive function, and collect everything in a list. That is, I want to do something like this:

```
(defn myfunc [x]
  (loop [x x retur '()]
    (when condition1
      (let [templist '()]
        (if condition2 (def templist (conj templist {:somekey someval})))
        (if condition3 (def templist (conj templist {:somekey someval})))
        (recur (+ x 1) (concat retur templist))))))
```

The problem is that in Clojure I can't rebind a let. I would like to avoid using global variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the functions in core use this pattern of chaining the same symbol through a `let` to conditionally build up a value. I had to change contition1 to an example that would not loop forever, and change the when to an if so it could return a value at the end of the loop.

```
(defn myfunc [x someval1 someval2 condition1 condition2 condition3]
  (loop [x x retur '()]
    (if (condition1 x)
      (let [templist '()
            templist (if condition2 (conj templist {:somekey1 someval1}) templist)
            templist (if condition3 (conj templist {:somekey2 someval2}) templist)]
        (recur (+ x 1) (concat retur templist)))
      retur)))
```

which can then be tested:

```
 user> (myfunc 0 1 2 #(< % 5) true true)
 ({:somekey2 2} {:somekey1 1} {:somekey2 2} {:somekey1 1} {:somekey2 2} 
  {:somekey1 1} {:somekey2 2} {:somekey1 1} {:somekey2 2} {:somekey1 1})

user> (myfunc 0 1 2 #(< % 5) true false)
({:somekey1 1} {:somekey1 1} {:somekey1 1} {:somekey1 1} {:somekey1 1})
```

The idea in the let is to have each stage change the value if the condition is true, or return it unchanged if the condition is false. This pattern gives functional code an imperative look and can help to make it clear how a value is constructed, though it can also be taken too far in using it to "convert" imperative logic into a functional program.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use threading macro `->` whenever I need to do some step oriented operations.

```
(defn myfunc [x]
  (loop [x x retur '()]
    (when condition1
        (let [r (-> '()
                    (#(if condition2 (conj % {:somekey 1}) %))
                    (#(if condition3 (conj % {:somekey 2}) %)))]
        (recur (+ x 1) (concat retur r))))))
```

Comment: The result of `myfunc` will always be `nil`. I guess `when` is not appropriate here.

Comment: just switch it for an if that returns retur when condition1 is not met

Comment: Yup, I just used the same structure as the question, coz the question was about updating the value

Answer (score 0):

You attempt to use imperative pattern that is getting the result by chain of assignments. Instead of this you could try to solve your problem in more declarative way which is more idiomatic for clojure as the functional language. For example

```
(defn myfunc [x]
  (loop [x x retur '()]
    (if condition1
      (recur (inc x) (concat retur
                             (when condition2 [{:somekey1 someval1}])
                             (when condition3 [{:somekey2 someval2}])))
      retur)))
```

Comment: I guess in the question the 2 if are independent whereas cond will sort of combine them and select first condition which holds true